# How to replicate jQuery ajax method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**The problem:** I'm trying to replicate the jQuery ajax method since I'm using XMLHttpRequest more than once in a script. However, I do not think including jQuery as a dependency is necessary since I would only be using a maximum of 3 methods from the jQuery library. Therefor I need a good way of replicating the jQuery's ajax method and so far I've gotten this far but please see explanation of output below the code example:

```
function ajax(obj) {
    /*
    obj = {
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'my/url/',
        success: function (response) {},
        error: function (response) {},
        isTrue: true
    }
    */

    var 
        response = null, // defaults to null
        complete = function (resp) {
            console.log(resp); // outputs the response
            response = resp;
        },
        error = function (resp) {
            response = resp;
        }, 
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open(obj.type || 'GET', obj.url, obj.isTrue || true);

    request.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                complete(request.responseText);
            } else {
                error(request.statusText);
            }
        }
    }

    request.send();

    return {
        done: function (callback) {
            callback(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I call the ajax function in another function:

```
var xhr = ajax({
            url: 'js/routes.js',
        }).done(function (resp) {
            console.log(resp); // outputs 'null'
        });
```

the response variable is null although the complete() function set the response variable to the value of the ajax .responseText.

**Question:** How can I return the value of .responseText from the request to the object the ajax function is returning so that I can do something with it in a callback function like I intend to do inside the .done() method of that object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your implementation. The 'done' function does not wait for response.

```
function ajax(obj) {
    /*
       obj = {
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'my/url/',
       success: function (response) {},
       error: function (response) {},
       isTrue: true
       }
       */

    var _callback = null,
        response = null, // defaults to null
        complete = function (resp) {
            if(_callback){
                _callback(resp);
            }
            response = resp;
        },
        error = function (resp) {
            if(_callback){
                _callback(resp);
            }
            response = resp;
        }, 
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open(obj.type || 'GET', obj.url, obj.isTrue || true);

    request.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                complete(request.responseText);
            } else {
                error(request.statusText);
            }
        }
    }

    request.send();

    return {
        done: function (callback) {
            if(response){
                callback(response);
            }else{
                _callback = callback;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT*

consider using a microlibrary instead of jQuery. Don't reinvent the wheel.
http://microjs.com/#ajax